# PayPal Sandbox Access via Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use .NET 3.5 app on Visual Studio 2008, running Mono 2.10.2 and Apache (with mod-mono) to perform a PayPal payment. I am using the PayPal sandbox, and the solution works perfectly when I debug or run locally. When running on the server with Mono, it times out after the following lines:

```
PayPalAPIAASoapBinding ws = PayPalUtils.BuildPayPalWebservice();

SetExpressCheckoutResponseType resp = ws.SetExpressCheckout(req);
```

with the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x0005f] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:752 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00069] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:367
```

I have run the ssl import for https://www.sandbox.paypal.com, and I have run mozroots import to bring in all ssl certs from Mozilla.

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome!